# RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager with header view that doesn't recycle

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**I want a ListView style RecyclerView with a header on top, AND I don't want the header view to get recycled, EVER.**

I'm totally new to `RecyclerView` and `LinearLayoutManager` but I think what I want shouldn't be too difficult by extending `LinearLayoutManager`.

Additional info in case needed, but I think the above is enough:

I already have a RecyclerView with a header view at position 0.  That part was easy enough with help from SO answers.  But the view gets recycled, which is causing lots of issues with the EditText views in the header (trying to keep focus, restore focus, keep the caret visible, not do weird things with auto-correct feature, keep typing while EditText is technically gone/recycled, etc).  So the simple solution would be to not have that view recycled, which I think is possible with a custom layout manager, but I have no idea where to begin.

I can't simply place the header view above my list, because I want it to scroll with the list (it's too tall to be fixed at the top of screen all the time).

Comment: It would be even easier to just assign that position a unique view type. Have `getItemViewType()` return a different value for position `0` from all the other positions. Then, that view will never be recycled, because there is nothing to recycle it to, other than position `0`.

Comment: I actually do that already, but I'm pretty sure it gets recycled anyway, although I'm not 100% sure how to check that.  I do know that onBind gets called for the header view again, each time it scrolls out of view and then back in... so that's one reason I think it still gets recycled.

Comment: All of the other bugs I'm seeing, and other reason I assume it gets recycled, are similar to what you would see if you have an EditText with the focus (keyboard open, typing in it) and you just remove it, without first giving something else focus.  Hard to explain but the keyboard/OS just isn't happy when that happens.

Comment: "I do know that onBind gets called for the header view again, each time it scrolls out of view and then back in... so that's one reason I think it still gets recycled" -- I would assume that's just making sure that you have up-to-date widget contents, given that the model data for that position might have changed. "if you have an EditText with the focus (keyboard open, typing in it) and you just remove it" -- oh, well, that's certainly happening, and it's not out of the question that a custom layout manager could address that, but I haven't played with one of those yet.

Answer (score 1):

`LayoutManager` has [LayoutManager#ignoreView(View)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#ignoreView(android.view.View)) interface which according to documentation,

> Flags a view so that it will not be scrapped or recycled.

Looks like what you need here

**EDIT** Google devs commented ([here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176602&can=1&q=reporter%3ADudka&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)) that this flag is serving some other purpose, so it is not gonna solve "RecyclerView Header" problem. However, they are working on solution, so hold on tight and stay tuned

Comment: oh wow, this could be a life-safer, will test this ASAP and report back -- thanks!

Comment: @eselk don't like bringing bad news, but it seems like "ignore" flag is serving some other purpose :( check this out: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176602&can=1&q=reporter%3ADudka&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out, but by chance have you used this before?  Trying to figure out what this part means "You can call this method only if your LayoutManger is in onLayout or onScroll callback." -- Do they mean onLayoutChildren, and I need to subclass LayoutManager to hook that?

Comment: Oh, never mind, bummer about that, seemed like exactly what I needed.  At least good to know "Google" is working on a new feature for this.

Comment: Yeah.. documentation is rather misleading.. I tried to use it the same as you, but no luck..